# React handleChange push values in nested object

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange, react-props

I've got a handleChange event that pushes data into the props

```
handleChange = input => e => {
    let target = e.target,
        type = target.type,
        value = target.value;

    this.setState({ 
        [input]: (type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : value) 
    });
};
```

in the input, I handle the change `onChange={onChange('services.cleaning')}`
Is there anyway i can push the data in the props as a nested object instead of as "services.cleaning"?

The onchange event

```
<Checkbox onChange={onChange('services.cleaning')} type='checkbox' name='cleaning' />
```

Comment: what's the structure of your object?

Comment: where are you calling onChange? paste the snippet

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: where's your `onChange` function?

Comment: its the handlechange function, I just pass it as onChange to the component

Comment: Will the depth of the nested prop always be equal to 2 ? can you have something like this 'prop1.prop2.prop3' ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé the structure can change, but I guess the max nested props amount would be 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

- First, you need to create a new object (shallow copy) of `this.state.services`
- Then you update the prop `cleaning` of this nested object
- Lastly you update the state with `this.setState({services: nestedObjectCreated})`

Here is the corresponding code :

```
handleChange = propKey => e => {
   const {target} = e;
   const {type, value} = target;
   const newValue = type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : value

   const [firstProp, ...otherProps] = propKey.split('.');

   if (!otherProps.length) {
      return this.setState({[firstProp] newValue});
   }

   const nestedObject = {...this.state[firstProp]};
   otherProps.reduce(
       (acc, val, index) => {
          if (index < otherProps.length - 1) {
             return acc[val];
          }
          acc[val] = newValue;,
       },
       nestedObject
   );

   this.setState({[firstProp]: nestedObject});
};
```

Comment: wow this is exactly what I needed, and thanks for explaining the solution, much love